# MacBook Pro internal hard drive failure: Missing EFI partition

Tags: hard-drive, backup, disk-utility, data-recovery, efi

2 days ago as I opened my laptop (mid 2012 MacBook Pro running Catalina), it booted in recovery mode.

Disk utility was showing me my internal hard drive and its partitions : **disk0s1** and **BOOTCAMP**. The **disk0s1** was greyed out and when I tried to mount it, it would stay unmounted. So I asked Disk Utility to verify the hard drive and it gives me the error : "*This disk doesn’t contain an EFI system partition. If you want to start up your computer with this disk or include it in a RAID set, back up your data and partition this disk.*" So I try to boot in Windows (BOOTCAMP) but get stuck at a black loading screen with an error.

Here is the output of various Terminal commands:

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *320.1 GB   disk0
   1: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF               279.9 GB   disk0s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                40.0 GB    disk0s2


sudo gpt -r show disk0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34     409606         
     409640  546609112      1  GPT part - FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF
  547018752   78123008      2  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  625141760        655         
  625142415         32         Sec GPT table
  625142447          1         Sec GPT header
```

I really don't know how I lost this EFI partition, the computer was working 8 hours ago...

After searching for an answer online it seems indeed possible to backup and restore the HD. Thus i install macOS on an external hard drive, and look for my data from there. But as you might have guessed, since **disk0s1** is unmounted I can't find any files... (except for the ones on BOOTCAMP, which sadly I don't care about).

I then download 4 apps that pretend to be able to recover data from an unmounted HD ("iboysoftdatarecovery", "mac_drw", "StellarDataRecovery", "m3datarecovery"). They all end up launching a deep scan of the HD that takes 7 hours to complete, without even finding a single file (one of them did find around 30 system files or something)

Can someone please give me any leads to recovering my data? I haven't backed up with Time Machine since March 2019 (8 months ago) and have most of my work and studies stored there.

Comment: As it's a 2012, have you tried popping the disk out and mounting externally? I had some unexplained disk problems with my 2012 once - turned out to be a dodgy cable. I'm now on my third. If it reads ok when mounted externally (in a caddy, say) then buy a new cable. The error is not the same, but worth a go. Check this link: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242837/hard-disk-problems-unsure-of-how-to-proceed

Comment: @FiddleDeDee klanomath has been helping me since yesterday, we managed to salvage the data but the disk seems definitely broken, we erased it. Thanks for your comment though :)

Comment: Grand. :thumbup:

Comment: Back with some info: it seems that you were right @FiddleDeDee, the SATA cable seems to be the culprit. Going to order a new one now.

Comment: Brilliant! :fireworks: :) It was @klanomath that helped me diagnose this the last time.

Comment: @NawraC Are you sure Nawra? Did you get some 2nd hint besides yesterday's  ICRC-errors monitored by S.M.A.R.T.? Or did you check the internal drive in an external case?

Comment: @klanomath well, the new SSD I installed internally displays the same errors. You could give it a look if you have the time, but it seems the cable is the problem.

Comment: @NawraC I checked the pics you've sent yesterday this morning and it's indeed the SATA-cable. When do you get the replacement?

Comment: @klanomath I should receive them by Friday